# AngularFire collection observable in NX Workspace triggered twice

Tags: angular, observable, angularfire2, nrwl-nx

I have an Angular (v 11.1.1)Project using @angular/fire (6.1.4) and a NX workspace.
I noticed that a query over a collection returns the data twice when invoked. If I use `take(1)` it returns only once, but this completes the stream and no db updates will occur anymore, therefore it is not what I want.

Below the code involved.

**DB service (db)**

```
import { AngularFirestore } from '@angular/fire/firestore';
import firebase from 'firebase/app';
  
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root',  // Provided in the ROOT Injector 
})
export class DbService {

  constructor(private firestoreRef: AngularFirestore) {

// Here just for TEST purposes, just to isolate irrelevant code (eg. component)

// This is triggered twice
firestoreRef.collection('places')
            .valueChanges()
            .subscribe(p => console.log('GOT DATA DIRECT'));
}
```

I want to keep the DB service generic inside a shared library, as I want to reuse it from other Apps in the NX workspace. The idea would be to pass new Firestore Keys, specific to the project.

To achieve this, I created a "Data-Access-Layer" module in a shared library and I import the module in the `app.module.ts`:

```
@NgModule({
  imports: [
    AngularFireModule.initializeApp(FirebaseConfigService.data),
    AngularFirestoreModule.enablePersistence(),
    AngularFireAuthModule
  ],
  providers: [FirebaseConfigService]
})
export class SharedDataAccessModule {
  static forRoot(data: FirebaseKeysModel): ModuleWithProviders<SharedDataAccessModule> {
    return {
      ngModule: SharedDataAccessModule,
      providers: [
        FirebaseConfigService,
        {
          provide: APP_INITIALIZER,
          multi: true,
          useFactory: (firebaseConfig: FirebaseConfigService) => () => {
            firebaseConfig.setFirebaseConfig(data);
          },
          deps: [FirebaseConfigService]
        }
      ]
    };
  }
}
```

The FirebaseConfig Service:

```
export class FirebaseConfigService {
  static data = {
    apiKey: '',
    authDomain: '',
    databaseURL: '',
    projectId: ''
  };

  setFirebaseConfig(moduleConfig: FirebaseKeysModel) {
    return new Promise<void>((resolve, reject) => {
      FirebaseConfigService.data.projectId = moduleConfig.projectId;
      FirebaseConfigService.data.apiKey = moduleConfig.apiKey;
      FirebaseConfigService.data.authDomain = moduleConfig.authDomain;
      FirebaseConfigService.data.databaseURL = moduleConfig.databaseURL;
    });
  }
}
```

This allows me to pass specific DB keys at application level (here in app.module):

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [AppComponent, NavigationComponent],
  imports: [
    ...
    // These are App specific keys for the DB
    SharedDataAccessModule.forRoot(environment.firebaseConfig),
  bootstrap: [AppComponent],
})
export class AppModule {}
```

Answer (score 1):

I found out that this is the expected behaviour with Firestore when using offline persistence (credits to Frank van Puffelen):

> when you attach a listener for the snapshot, it immediately fires with the local state of the data (if any). Then it checks against the server, which may take some time, and fires again with the state from the server, if that is different from the local cache (or you've requested to get called with metadata changes too).